# How to check if my build version is above x.x.x in perl

Tags: perl, version

I'm  trying to check if my etcd version is above 3.4.0 or not

Below is the command I use to fetch the version

`podman exec -it etcd-pod-etcd etcdctl version`

The final output from the above command will be in string format
`$output = '3.4.15'`

I tried to validate the version in the following way `$output =~ 3.4`

But the problem here is if the version changes to 3.5.x I will have to change my script again.

What is the best way to check if the version is above 3.4.x? Is there any modules in Perl to do the following?

Comment: How is the question related to java, perl or python?

Comment: Please don't add unrelated programming language tags to your question. It can increase the risk of your question's being down-voted and even closed due to its "annoyance factor" due to the disappointment that occurs when someone comes to the question expecting relevance in their language of interest only to find no relevance at all.

Comment: I have removed the Python and Java tags for you, but I still would advise you to [edit] and improve your question. The [ask] and [tour] links can help you with this task.

Comment: Gotcha @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl's [version objects and `version` pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/version) make it trivial:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010; # This needs at least 5.10, which hopefully isn't an issue these days
use feature qw/say/;
use version 0.77;

my $vers = version->parse('3.4.15');
if ($vers > v3.4.0) {
    say "Version $vers is new enough.";
} else {
    say "Version $vers is too old. You need to upgrade.";
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting read: https://xdg.me/version-numbers-should-be-boring/

Comment: @briandfoy Interesting but not really relevant as it's about giving version numbers to modules, not so much comparing version numbers of a known format. And how much of it even applies to modern versions of perl and the module-manipulating modules mentioned? 2009 was a long time ago.

Comment: All of it applies. What do you think is different with version numbers now?